# Where can I find information about setting up profiles for web development?

Tags: html, web, profile

I am creating a website with HTML+CSS and Javascript that allows users to create Dungeons & Dragons character sheets for my specific system (FoA). I want to set up profiles that allow for the sheets to save to their profile for use over gaps in time. I am completely new to anything regarding profiles, but I don't even know where to start.

I have attempted looking up information however I can't find any - perhaps because I don't know where to even begin.

I would love some resources on introductory profile creation and perhaps the ability to have user-specific instances of an html form. Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: Where to start is by reading about `CRUD` and taking a [CRUD TUTORIAL](https://www.google.com/search?q=crud+tutorial) -- Also familiarize yourself with what [CRUD is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CRUD)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend to try some service that handles login and user profiles for you, like Amazon Cognito or Okta.

But after logging the user in, you would still need to store the data in some kind of database, for which the app would need some kind of backend.

Or for simplicity’s sake it may be plausible to even use local storage in browser, if you expect the user to use always the same device.